# RDP session error: because of a protocol error (0x112f) the remote session will be disconnected

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I've initiated the discussion on MSDN:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/72ceca09-ab4a-4689-896c-6c86697333d6.

I found that the RDP ActiveX control seems to be a black box. It uses well but sometimes there would be some strange errors.

Today I encountered another error: I connect to a remote Win8 Pro machine through the RDP ActiveX control on another Win8 Pro, when I played a HD video for about a few seconds, the RDP session will be disconnected. The reason is as what the title said: because of a protocol error (0x112f) the remote session will be disconnected... I've made some search but got no correct solution. It seems that the issue might lie in the resolution, but I am not sure.

The most strange thing for me was that if I play the HD with Windows media player, it works well. But if the HD video is played with Win8 Video app, the issue occurred.

The following thread made a long discussion: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/4523ce86-9a0b-4e6c-90d1-225ddda67ce5/. But it has no good to my issue.

Other articles suggested to set the RDP attribute bitmapcachepersistenable to false, but it also doesn't help.

Does any one know how to resolve it?

Thank you all.

Comment: Does anybody know something about it? The strangest thing here is that if I play the HD with Windows media player, it works well. But if the HD video is played with Win8 Video app, the issue occurred.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For Microsoft's RDP sample, this is also bug.http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Remote-Desktop-app-461567af

Answer (score 3):

I suddenly started getting this error on a Remote Desktop connection that had been working fine for 5 months.

I would get the 0x112f protocol error when trying Remote Desktop, so then I tried TeamViewer instead, and if I just connected with TeamViewer and disconnected again, Remote Desktop would work again.

After lots and lots of trial and error, I found out that it works much more consistently if I disable the option "Use all my monitors for the remote session" on the Display tab of the client settings.

[image]

Still not sure why it suddenly became an issue after working fine for several months though.

Comment: I also find unchecking "Use all my monitors ..." helped. My remote server is an old Z620 with sufficient memory (7/32 GB was in use). The `0x112f ` error shall kick in randomly, stopping me to use all local monitors over RDP. Restarting the remote server helps to resume using all local monitors.

Answer (score 0):

check following article, basically it is related with RDP theme.
http://computerboom.blogspot.com/2008/08/solution-because-of-protocol-error-this.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same 0x112f issue when using mstsc client today. The issue is gone after I changed the color depth from 32bit to 16bit in mstsc. I don't know why but it works. My remote desktop OS is Win10 and local OS is also Win10.

EDIT: For several days of using 16bit in mstsc, the 0x112f issue re-appeared several times. But the frequency is much lower than 32bit. This temp workaround is ok for me. I searched web, some users say it's because of low memory at the host. I checked the remote Win10 virtualized, it consumed 3.7G out of 4G physical memory. Maybe it's the cause. I've no privilege to reboot it for further test.

Answer (score -3):

The width and height of RDP session is better to be a even number, otherwise, it may cause problems, especially you are connecting to non-Windows server version.

Comment: Can you give more info? Why does this matter? What resources back this up? Have you tested it? What happens if it's not an even number?

Comment: Even if you're right (which I don't think you are - source, please), this has nothing to do with RDP protocol errors disconnecting a Windows-to-Windows RDP session.